# How to use $$NOW in $match block of aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Given a document added to a collection "sample" as so:

```
db.sample.insert({"activeOn":ISODate("2000-01-01")})
```

I think that I should be able to match that document with the following aggregation

```
db.sample.aggregate([{"$match":{"activeOn":{"$lte":"$$NOW"}}}])
```

but no documents are found.
I'm using MongoDB version 4.2.3

What am I missing about using the $$NOW system variable in a $match block?

Answer (score 8):

From the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions) docs:

> The $match query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e. $match does not accept raw aggregation expressions. To include aggregation expression in $match, use a $expr query expression:

Is [$$NOW](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#variable.NOW) a [raw aggregation expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions)? yes as it's a system variable:

> Expressions can include field paths, literals, system variables, expression objects, and expression operators. Expressions can be nested.

So all we have to do is use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) like so:

```
db.sample.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          "$activeOn",
          "$$NOW"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wiVAfcSO1L1)